# How Many Squares In A Grid Of Dots?

Tags: geometry

how many squares can I make by connecting the dots in a 100 by 100 grid of dots. For example in a 4 by 4 grid I can make a total of 20 squares, in a 3 by 3 grid, I can make 6. Is there any general formula to figure this out (and if so why that formula is true).

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.